# Express redirect wrong url

Tags: node.js, express

When use express res function redirect(url), i'm redirected to the wrong url !

My website URL is mywebsite.com :

```
function myroute(app) {
    app.get(/route, function(req, res) {
        var url = getMyUrl();
        console.log(url); // https://otherwebsite.com/foo?bar=baz [OK]
        res.redirect(url); // redirect to https://mywebsite.com/foo?bar=baz [WRONG!]
    });
}
```

I don't know why express redirect to mywebsite.com with good parameters instead of otherwebsite.com

No idea why...

This bug occurs on production. On my develop environment the redirect URL is the good url.

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

I also tried with:

```
res.location(url);
```

and

```
res.setHeader(302, {Location: url});
```

But it always redirect to the wrong URL...
My url variable is good but I receive this header response:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
X-Powered-By: Express
Location: https://mywebsite.com/foo?bar=baz
Vary: Accept\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 170
Date: Fri, 13 Jul 2018 21:52:18 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
```

**EDIT 2**

Ok more tests here :

```
res.redirect("https://www.google.fr/toto?key=value"); // https://mywebsite.com/toto?key=value **[fail]**

res.redirect("https://www.google.fr/toto"); // https://mywebsite.com/toto **[fail]**

res.redirect("https://www.google.fr"); // https://www.google.fr **[success]**
```

It seems to not redirect to the domain I want if I add a path. Any idea ?

**EDIT 3**

Maybe it's caused by my vhost ?

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName mywebsite.com

ProxyRequests     Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:5001/
<Location />
    ProxyPassReverse /
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Location>

SSLCertificateFile ...
SSLCertificateKeyFile ...
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: add 'http://' or 'https://' to you url , var url =  'http://' + getMyUrl();

Comment: https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.redirect

Comment: I already have https://, edited.

Comment: how are you getting getMyUrl

Comment: You are going to have to give us a lot more code for anyone to be able to help you with this problem. Also I can't think of any situation where an app route would be wrapped in a function like that. The redirect syntax is correct.

Comment: I have a static part of my url and I just concat the end of the url. Maybe is it because the two websites have a common part of their domain ? My website is website-prefix.com and the other website is website.com. Maybe a bug in the redirect function parsing the url ? I'm not able to find the declaration of the redirect function in node_modules to debug it...

Comment: https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/43c8764465686ba108fcba0adff0493c51269730/lib/response.js#L469

Comment: Ok, so i tried to debug, here is the response object when redirecting : https://pastebin.com/5Ha5pPqW as you can see the url at line 349 is the good url (but after that i'm redirected to https://kimsufi-notifier.com/uk/order/kimsufi.xml?reference=1801sk18 without reason...

Comment: I edited my question, anyone has an idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Providing an actual answer this time, as my previous one was (rightfully so) deleted.

The incorrect URL redirections are definitely caused by:

ProxyPassReverse /

As [this](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassreverse) is what such directive does:

"lets Apache httpd adjust the URL in the Location, Content-Location and URI headers on HTTP redirect responses."

In my case, removing this directive was causing other internal redirection issues in my application, so I was trying to find out a way to add exceptions to it.

However, it turns out I never needed ProxyPassReverse (only ProxyPass) if I adjust the 'mountpath' of my Express node js configuration to match the path of the proxy server. Not sure if this answer will help you as an actual solution, but it managed to solve it on my node application using Apache as reverse proxy.

Answer (score 2):

I believe [301](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301) needs to be included.

Try changing `res.redirect(url)` to `res.status(301).redirect(url)` and see if it fixes the issue.

Comment: same problem :/